# Validate a comma separated email list

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression to validate a comma separated email list.

I would like to validate the complete list in the first place, then split(";"), then trim each array value (each email) from the split.

I would like to validate the following expressions:

```
EMAIL,EMAIL  --> Ok
EMAIL, EMAIL  --> Ok
EMAIL , EMAIL  --> Ok
EMAIL , , EMAIL  --> Wrong
EMAIL , notAnEmail , EMAIL  --> Wrong
```

I know there's many complex expressions for validating emails but I don't need anything fancy, this just works for me: `/\S+@\S+\.\S+/;`

I would like plain and simple JS, not jQuery. Thanks.

Edit: I've already considered fist validate then split, but with the expressions I've tried so far, this will be validated as two correct emails:

```
EMAIL, EMAIL  .  EMAIL
```

I would like to validate the list itself as much as every email.

Comment: Why would you want to first validate, then split? It would be much easier to split and then loop through each email.

Comment: If you split, the second email will not be valid. It would be something  like `email1@gmail.com  .   email2@gmail.com`. This will not validate when you use the regex I provided.

Comment: EMAIL and email@email.com are not comparable strings.

Answer (score 14):

An easier way would be to remove spaces and split the string first:

```
var emails = emailList.replace(/\s/g,'').split(",");
```

This will create an array. You can then iterate over the array and check if the element is not empty and a valid emailadres.

```
var valid = true;
var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
     if( emails[i] == "" || ! regex.test(emails[i])){
         valid = false;
     }
}
```

note: I got the the regex [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: It doesn't validate the list.
Also it does not validate "EMAIL,EMAIL  ,  EMAIL "  when I do validate the array split result.

Comment: It should, what does the list look like that you are trying to validate?

Comment: @user2256799, You could remove spaces safely by calling `replace()` before you split the string into an array. `"foo@bar.com, pow@wow.com".replace(" ", "").split(",");`

Comment: @Flowpoke would use .replace(/\s/g,'') to get rid of all white space in the string and then do the split. works great.

Answer (score 6):

I am using the Regex from many years and code is same. 
I believe this works for every one:

```
^(\w+((-\w+)|(\.\w+))*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}\s*?,?\s*?)+$
```

Be happy :)

Comment: Where have you seen that TLDs are limited to 4 characters? See http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db also, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples to see some valid emails not covered by your regex.

Comment: @Toto - mostly we use .com, .org, .inc, .co.aus, etc. So as per majority I recommend 4, if anyone wanna change according to his domain, otherwise its perfect and never got any problem from my work done.

Answer (score 5):

Also note that you'll want to get rid of extra spaces so an extra step needs to be added as follows:

```
var emailStr = "felipe@google.com   , felipe2@google.com, emanuel@google.com\n";


function validateEmailList(raw){
    var emails = raw.split(',')


    var valid = true;
    var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
        if( emails[i] === "" || !regex.test(emails[i].replace(/\s/g, ""))){
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}


console.log(validateEmailList(emailStr))
```

By adding `.replace(/\s/g, "")` you make sure all spaces including new lines and tabs are removed. the outcome of the sample is true as we are getting rid of all spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @crisbeto's comment but if you are sure that this is how you want to do it, you can do it by matching the following regex:

`^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$`

Comment: @user2256799, Well you replace `EMAIL` with the actual email

Comment: @sshashank124 please could you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797093/regex-email-validation-that-allows-only-hyphens-in-the-middle-of-the-domain-and

Answer (score -1):

```js
const regExp = new RegExp(/^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$/);
const dom = document.getElementById("regExDom");
const result = regExp.test("test@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com,test3@test.com")
console.log("Regex test => ", result)
dom.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="regExDom"></div>
```

Comment: this is failing for this string 
test.test@gmail, test, also failing for many invalid string