# Regular expression to validate email address so that multiple Email should not be entered comma separated

Tags: jquery, email

What will be regular expression to validate email address so that multiple Email should not be entered comma separated, it should be semi colon separated . Is below mentioned expression is valid?

```
function validateEmail($email) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                return emailReg.test($email);
```

This Regular expression is also validating Email that are comma separated. What I want is that For example : **john1@gmail.com,john2@gmail.com** this string is entered by user than error will reflect.

But it should validate successfully to this:
**john1@gmail.com;john2@gmail.com**

Comment: Your question is: "Is below mentioned expression is valid?" Well, test it with a online regex tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [semicolon separated email validation in javascript only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860412/semicolon-separated-email-validation-in-javascript-only)

Comment: @DouwedeHaan .I have updated my question. Can you please assist for the same.